# double NOT operator in Javascript Confusion (using it inside Vuejs instance)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, logical-operators

I'm using Vue2 inside HTML.

Could anyone explains why **isNameSet** variable is **undefined** whereas it is set to **!!name**, and since **name** is a string (**name: "yahya"**) and so **!!name** it is converted to **true**, so **isNameSet** should be **true**, right !?

Is it Vuejs problem, or what exactly ?!

Code :

```
<body>
<div id="my-id">
    <h1> Welcome {{ name }} </h1>
    <h2> {{ '!name : ' + !name }} </h2>
    <h2> {{ '!!name : ' + !!name }} </h2>
    <h2> {{ 'isNameSet: ' + isNameSet }} </h2>
    <h3 v-text="isNameSet ? 'Your name is set!' : 'Please, Set a name !' " >  </h3>
    <h3 v-text="!!name ? 'Your name is set!' : 'Please, Set a name !' " >  </h3>
</div>

<script src="vue.js"></script>
<script>
    var vm = new Vue({
        el: "#my-id",
        data: {
            name: "yahya",
            isNameSet: !!name
        },
    })
    console.log("typeof name      : ", typeof name)
    console.log("typeof isNameSet : ", typeof isNameSet)
</script>
```

[image: console]

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: `name` and `isNameSet` are not variables, they're properties of the `vm` object.

Comment: `name` is the same as `window.name`.

Comment: So we cannot set the value of a property based on another property of the same object ?!

Comment: No. Objects don't create variable scopes.

Comment: Not a full dupe since it's primarily Vue question, but as for JS part, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are accessing it is how you would if it is a variable.

Even if you do access it like an object i.e

```js
let obj = {
  a: "this is A",
  b: obj.a
}
```

it won't work.

You are currently defining what `obj` is. How can you get a value you are currently trying to define?

That's just like doing the following:

```js
let a = a
```

You can however just initialize first and set right after

```js
let obj = { a: "this is A" }
obj.b = obj.a
```

or a getter which may/may not be the right answer

```js
let obj = {
  a: "this is A",

  get b() {
    return this.a
  }
}
```

That will permanently reflect value of `obj.a` and not just on initialization.

If you're using vue, i suggest just sticking with `computed`.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, `const person = { firstname: "yahya", booleanValue: !!person.firstname }` this gave **Cannot access 'person' before initialization**. Thank you.

Comment: updated the answer to include an alternative

Answer (score 2):

data must be a function that return object:

```
data() {
  return {
    name: "yahay",
  }
}
```

and you can access data property from for example computed property:

```
computed: {
  isNameSet() {
    return !!this.name
  }
}
```

Comment: yes this makes sense to me. But the question still there, why is that ?! why we cannot set the value of a property based on another property of the same object ? is it because the object is not yet initialized ?!